# Except with the rectiation of the qur'an do we need to seek refuge from satan when quoting/reading verses?

Tags: quran, fiqh, practical-islam, reading-quran

Allah the almighty told us in the Qur'an:

> So when you recite the Qur'an, [first] seek refuge in Allah from Satan, the expelled [from His mercy]. ([16:98](https://legacy.quran.com/16/98))

If taken literally we only need to do the isti'adah or ta'awud (Seeking refuge in Allah from Satan) when we are about to recite the Qur'an.

This means that in any other case it might not be necessary but for example in the prayer it could be a disputed topic. AS the Qur'an recitation is part of the prayer, some may say prayer is a different worship and has its own rules (assuming there's no secondary backup for any of the possible opinions). But what if we read or quote a verse in a news paper or article or online or search for it or in a speech or discussion. What if in a discussion we want to give an evidence from the Qur'an do we need to seek refuge in Allah from Satan?

A bit more general if we actually are not reciting the Qur'an do we need to seek refuge in Allah from Satan when we are about to quote or read verses from the Qur'an? What is the appropriate ruling on this?